# javascript pop-up with print screen button

Tags: javascript

I have a basic web page that uses a simple javascript validate function to verify field content before returning TRUE to allow submission.  If validate is false, then it just displays an alert() and returns FALSE.

However, I need to modify this, so that if everything validates, a pop-up appears that says "You are about to submit this form and agree to XYZ.  Click OK to continue, Cancel to leave, or Print to print this page"

In other words, I need an alert box with an OK, CANCEL, and PRINT button (the print button actually would print the page itself and then allow user to click OK and move forward with the submit command.

** EDIT: I should have clarified, using a modal pop-up is causing that modal to appear in the print screen.  so maybe a close.modal followed by a print.screen set of commands?  library isn't an option because we are confined to a single page with no external loads of any kind because this is inside of a banking platform and they only allow html/inline-css/on-page javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom code to do this since there is no way to add buttons to window.confirm.

Libraries like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/simpledialog-quickstart.html), [DOJO](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/Dialog), etc have a modal dialogs which would allow you do do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QRm4c/1/

You could always just use a `<div>` to make a fake one.

```
<div id="confirmation">
    <p>Blah, blah, blah</p>
    <form>
        <input type="button" name="ok" id="ok" value="OK" />
        <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="button" name="confirm" id="confirm" value="Confirm" />
    </form>
</div>
```

epascarello is right, window.confirm can't do this.